# Vue dynamic route doesn't show content on manual navigation or page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a `Projects` view/route, which loops through a JSON list and populates multiple `ProjectCard` components, each with links to dynamic pages with differing content. So, the user flows goes something like:

- User lands on Index page
- Clicks on `router-link to="/projects"`
- On the `Projects` view, they see multiple `ProjectCards`, each linking to a url similar to `/projects/foo` or `projects/bar`. These show the `ProjectPage` component.

The `ProjectPage` component renders as it should if the user navigates as above. The problem is however, that if a user should copy/paste the full path, like `website.com/projects/foo` OR if they refresh the page, the relevant props will not show up. If you look at my `ProjectPage` component below as an example, the `<h1>` will render properly as that's just some static text, but my `<p>` tag will not render at all as it's not receiving the props for some reason. Checking the component using the Vue debugger shows me that `textString` is undefined upon refreshing or manual navigation.

You can see the issue happen at this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-bassi-50p8j?file=/src/views/ProjectPage.vue)

Cutting out some irrelevant code for the sake of brevity.

## `Projects.vue` Route

```html
<template>
    <ProjectCard
        v-for="project in ProjectList"
        :key="project.id"
        :url="project.src"
    />
</template>

<script>
    import ProjectList from "@/assets/lists/projectList.json";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                ProjectList
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

## `ProjectCard.vue` component

```html
<template>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'ProjectPage', params: { testString: 'This is a test string', id: url } }" >
<template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            url: String // A simple string like table or scissors
        }
    };
</script>
```

## `ProjectPage.vue` component

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Project Page</h1>
        <p>{{ testString }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            testString: String
        }
    };
</script>
```

## Router `index.js` File

```js
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/projects",
        name: "Projects",
        component: Projects
    },
    {
        path: "/projects/:id",
        name: "ProjectPage",
        component: ProjectPage,
        props: true
    },
    {
        path: "*",
        component: FourOhFour
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes
});
```

As you can see, my router is set up to handle history mode, and my webserver (this is being hosted on Netlify) has also been configured with the appropriate redirects.

I suspect it has to do with the fact that the only way the `ProjectPage` can receive a prop is via the `ProjectCard`. If a user never interacts with the component, the ProjectPage never gets the props it needs passed onto it.

How can I reformat my components and views around to navigate around this issue? Note that I'm simply using a JSON file and don't have any kind of external API that I can call to get the data I need populated and there's no way for me to avoid the JSON file in question. The JSON is structured like this:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Foo",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet",
    "altText": "Foo",
    "src": "foo",
    "image": {
      "webp": "/images/projects/foo.webp",
      "jpg": "/images/projects/foo.jpg"
    },
    "texts": [
      "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      "lorem ipsum a second time again"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: you might want to persist the JSON data on reload or manual navigation with local storage or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reached a solution that works.

The problem was, as I expected, that the props will never get the chance to get passed onto the component on a refresh or manual navigation to the page. What happens is that Vue will route the user to the correct component, however it has no idea what props go where, since it hasn't been specified anywhere. Normally, in a situation where you'd use a dynamic route like this you'd be getting some data from an API, so that functionality would've just been a no-brainer to include because you'd need to fetch things anyway. I'm using a static JSON file however, so I didn't feel like it was necessary for me to include a way for fetching the data initially, but obviously it doesn't work like that.

So, the solution is a simple one: Fetch the data when a user enters the component. Using the Vue Router `beforeRouteEnter` or `afterRouteEnter` methods is all it takes, like this:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Project Page</h1>
        <p>{{ title }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ProjectList from "@/assets/lists/projectList.json";

    export default {
        name: "ProjectPage",
        data() {
            return {
                title: null
            };
        },
        methods: {
            setProjectPage(projectDetails) {
                this.title = projectDetails.title;
            }
        },
        beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
            const currentProject = ProjectList.find(project => project.id === to.params.id);
            next(page => {
                page.setProjectPage(currentProject);
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

So now, before navigation Vue will grab the JSON, populate whatever data() it has to populate, and everything shows up fine. This actually makes passing props from the `ProjectCards` redundant, seeing as I just have access to the full JSON object anyways, so that part can be removed and it can be a simple link to the Component instead. How this behaves with things like caching, I'm not sure yet, but I'll burn that bridge when I cross it.

A small caveat to keep in mind with using `beforeRouteEnter` is that Vue won't have access to the component's data or props as it happens before the `created()` hook gets called. The solution is very simple of course, Vue Router's `next()` will give access to the *next* component that is being navigated to, so you can call any methods in `beforeRouteEnter` by accessing it in the `next()` portion of the code.